# SSMS Query Comparing Two Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to query from a multitude of tables right now for the purposes of graphing in Tableau. Among other data, each line of the query currently contains the following important to this question...

| Name | Enrollment Status | Date Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company 1 | Enrolled | NULL |
| Company 2 | Unenrolled | 12 |
| Company 3 | Unenrolled | 41 |
| Company 4 | Enrolled | 2 |

Where Date Diff is using the DATEDIFF() function (month) to find how long its been since their status was updated. I want to compare Enrollment Status and Date Diff so that if a status has changed within the past 3 months, a column will display "Recently Enrolled" or "Recently Unenrolled" instead of just "Enrolled" and "Unenrolled".

Comment: So what's stopping you? Seems like you could just use a `CASE` expression.

Comment: @Larnu I'm not the greatest at SQL and had been trying to use if statements for a while with minimal luck..

Comment: You can't use `IF` statements in a `SELECT` statement, they are logical flow operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a `case` expression?

```
select name,
       (case when status = 'Enrolled' and datediff < 3
             then 'Recently enrolled'
             when status = 'Unenrolled' and datediff < 3
             then 'Recently unenrolled'
             else status
        end) as new_status
```